# Mathematica code to $\LaTeX$

Tags: latex, syntax-highlighting

```
paramOskRavan[\[Gamma]_, t_, t0_] := 
Module[{X, Y, Z, P, \[Tau], B, T, N, \[Tau]1}, \[Gamma] == {X[t], Y[t], Z[t]};
T = D[\[Gamma], t]/Simplify[Sqrt[D[\[Gamma], t].D[\[Gamma], t]]];
N = D[T, t]/Simplify[Sqrt[D[T, t].D[T, t]]];
\[Tau] = Simplify[\[Gamma] + N u + T v /. {t -> t0}];
Return[\[Tau]]
]
```

How do I insert this code into $\LaTeX$, so that it looks like it does in Wolfram *Mathematica*?

Comment: This is a job for https://github.com/rsmenon/pygments-mathematica

Answer (score 1):

why don't you select your code, right click/ copy as/ lateX?

Doing so you will get:
$$
\text {paramOskRavan} (\gamma \_, \text {t$ \_ $}, \text {t0$ \_ $})\t
  ext { := }\t
  ext {Module}\left[\{X, Y, Z, P, \tau, B, T, 
     N, \text {$\tau $1}\}, \gamma = \{X (t), Y (t), Z (t)\}; 
        T = \frac {\frac {\partial\gamma} {\partial t}} {\t
             ext {Simplify}\left[\sqrt {\frac {\partial\gamma} \
{\partial t}.\frac {\partial\gamma} {\partial t}} \r ight]}; 
        N = \frac {\frac {\partial T} {\partial t}} {\t
             ext {Simplify}\left[\sqrt {\frac {\partial T} {\partial \
t}.\frac {\partial T} {\partial t}} \r ight]};\t
        au = \text {Simplify}[\gamma + N u + 
          T v\text { /. }\, \{t\to\text {t0}\}];\t
     ext {Return}[\tau] \r ight]
$$